# Can't iterate through tuple in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, tuples, gurobi

So here's how I make `st`:

```
st = {}
cursor.execute('select * from store limit 6')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    st[row[0]] = row[0], row[1]
```

And here's an easy way to see how I'm trying to get the first element of the tuple:

```
for i in len(st):
    print st[i][0]
```

It tells me `type "int" is not iterable`.

Where I'm actually trying to use it is down here:

```
costtotal = m.addVars(st[i][0], dc[i][0], obj=mileage[i,j], name="costtotal")
```

But it keeps telling me long object not iterable there. That's part of some gurobi code to iteratively make constraints for an optimization model. I am trying to make them by using the first element of the values of st as the variable name.

The values for `st` are just numbers. The simple loop demonstrates my problem, it is not necessary to get the syntax of the`m.addVars()` to understand my problem I don't think.

Comment: .... what are you trying to do `for i in len(st)` there? `len(<whatever>)` will always return an integer, you cannot iterate over integers... what `tuple`? `st` is a *dict*

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(st)):` to avoid the `type "int" is not iterable` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(len) function returns an integer indicating the length of a collection. You need the range() function:

```
for i in range(len(st)):
    print(st[i][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in len(st):
```

You're trying to iterate over an int (the `len()` return value), as it's said.

And an `int` isn't an iterable object.

Maybe you meant :

```
for i in st.items():
    print(i[0])
```

or

```
for i in st.items():
    print(i[1])
```

depending if you want the key or the value?

You can also directly iterate over `st.keys()` or `st.values()` then.